# Which algorithm is used in random.randint function of python?

Tags: python, random

Which algorithm is used in the following code?

```
import random
random.randint(0,99)
```

Linear congruential generator? or something else?

Comment: You can view the [code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/random.py) and [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) online. These should answer your question.

Comment: The default RNG is Mersenne Twister, but as the docs mention: "Class Random can also be subclassed if you want to use a different basic generator of your own devising". It's also easy to specify `SystemRandom` as the generator if you want a higher grade of randomness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

> Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator.